# What about of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/10^{N_n}$ as transcendental number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request, transcendental-numbers, primorial

In this post we denote the primorial of order $n$ as $N_n=\prod_{k=1}^n p_k,$
where thus $p_k$ denotes the $k$th prime number.

[This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental) of the Wikipedia's article dedicated to transcendental numbers tell us some classic examples of transcendental numbers defined as infinite series and involving certain powers of two or well factorial numbers. I wondered if is in the literarature some series (I evoke similar than previous ones, see the example below) involving primorials.

For example I wondered if is feasible to prove or refute that  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-N_n}\tag{1}$$
is a transcendental number.

> **Question.** I would like to know* if is in the literature that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-N_n}$ is a transcendental number. In this case please refer the literature and I try to find and read such fact. In case that it isn't known please add what work can be done about the deduction concerning to if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-N_n}$ can be proven/disproven as a trasncendental number. **Many thanks.**

*I've no intutition about if $(1)$ can be a transcendental number.

Comment: Intuitively, this number should be transcendental because the sum converges quite fast and we probably can apply Liouville's theorem. But I am not sure.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback and reasoning @Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-N_n}$ and $x_m = \sum_{n=1}^m 10^{-N_n}$. 
Then $x_m$ is rational with denominator $10^{N_m}$.  Since for any positive integer $k$,  $$|x - x_m| \le 2 \cdot 10^{-N_{m+1}} < \left(10^{N_m}\right)^{-k}$$
for sufficiently large $m$, $x$ is a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) and therefore is transcendental by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Many thanks for your proof.

Comment: Also the sequence $a_n=2^{N_n}$, for $n\geq 1$, (or also $10^{N_n}$) is an irrationality sequence. If you know **how to find an example of a transcendental sequence** (the definition is in last section of the  Wikipedia's article [*Irrationality sequence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrationality_sequence) ) **involving primorials** feel free to comment it here (I don't know if  $a_n=2^{N_n}$ is an example of a transcendental sequence).